# When and why did our galaxy gain the name "Milky Way"?

Tags: etymology

The Milk Way as the name for our galaxy has always been interesting to me, and I've heard that it has been used as far back as the 13th century, where abouts did it originate and why was it chosen?

As a starting point: the [Milky Way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milky_Way) Wikipedia page lists a derivation from Greek via Latin.

Comment: Hello and welcome to EL&U. You might want to add the wikipedia article ["Milky Way"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milky_Way) to your question (use the [edit] link) as a starting point. It mentions a derivation from Greek via Latin.

Comment: No worries, I'll add that to the post

Comment: Research, not just links to research, is expected on ELU.

Comment: Hello user43218.  For etymology questions, it is good to start by checking [Etymology Online](https://www.etymonline.com/word/Milky%20Way), and if you still have questions, describe them specifically.  Since the etymology is described on Wikipedia and Etymonline, the question as it stands looks to me like one that can be answered with generally available references, which are off-topic on this site.

Comment: @user43218 [Good](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/421806/when-and-why-did-our-galaxy-gain-the-name-milky-way?noredirect=1#comment1009784_421806). I've expanded your reference to note the relevant information from the link. This forms part of the 'research' you present to the community. The next step is to explain the parts of your question that the research doesn't adequately address. The community can then attempt to fill in that missing information by way of an answer, which you can vote up or down for usefulness and/or tick as the answer you accept.

Comment: Note that "galaxy" itself contains the same 'milk' root; the metaphor has been going for a **long** time.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on an Astronomy site.

Comment: It's already been answered, what good would closing it do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OED describes the etymology well. The first mention of a classical term equating to "milky way" is by Ovid in post-classical Latin of the 13th century *lactae via*.

However a number of similar terms were in use for the same thing in classical Latin and prior to that in Ancient Greek.

> Etymology:  < milky adj. + way n.1 and int.1, after classical Latin
>   lactea via, denoting the Milky Way (once in Ovid; 13th cent. in
>   post-classical Latin in British sources). Other expressions denoting
>   the Milky Way are also found in classical Latin and post-classical
>   Latin, e.g. lacteus orbis  (Cicero), lacteus circulus  (Pliny);
>   compare milky circle n. at milky adj. Special uses 2. In ancient Greek
>   it is denoted simply by γάλα  (see galactic adj.); in Hellenistic
>   Greek also by ὁ τοῦ γάλακτος κύκλος .